# How to resolve "Deserialization of Untrusted Data" error reported by Checkmarx

Tags: c#, security, azure-devops, asp.net-core-webapi, checkmarx

We have integrated Checkmarx static code analyzer tool in Azure DevOps Pipeline. While running our pipeline, we are getting "Deserialization of Untrusted Data" error with high risk in below lines of code. Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

**C# Code:**

```
using System.Text.Json;

string reqBodyParams = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
var requestData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CalcRequestBody>(reqBodyParams);
```

**CalcRequestBody Class:**

```
public class CalcRequestBody
{
  public string CalcFormula { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have finally found the solution for "Deserialization of Untrusted Data" error getting from Checkmarx tool.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var requestData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CalcRequestBody>(reqBodyParams, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
   TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None
});
```

Comment: That seems like a bug in [tag:checkmarx].  [`System.Text.Json` intentionally does not even support polymorphism out of the box](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29601), so effectively it's always configured with `TypeNameHandling.None`.

Comment: @dbc, Could you please share your inputs as an answer. Then I will accept your answer. Thank you.