# Deserialization of Untrusted Data in Test method

Tags: c#, .net, azure, checkmarx

I have this line of code which reads data from appSettings.json and deserializes it to a TestData class

```
testData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestData>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("appSettings.json"));
```

While Checkmarx did its regular scan it marked this as high vulnerability with the message: "*Deserialization_of_Untrusted_Data*"

I went over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca5360 but I am not able to figure this out.  Should I suppress this warning.  If no, what should I do to achieve the same and if not, how?

Comment: Alternatively specific to the "appSettings.json" file you can go with the IOptions pattern or configuration stuff to read the data

Comment: This does not seems specific to "Azure" tag. There are some answers regarding this already. Can you check if this helps?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70959274/how-to-resolve-deserialization-of-untrusted-data-error-reported-by-checkmarx